# Help me to park my car

Tags: mechanical-engineering

My front gate is 13 feet  wide and length is 20 feet  and the road is 11 feet wide I have a Scorpio SUV  can it be park in my house

Comment: Have you tried? what was your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a big challenge. Definitely is much smaller than standard, 9 meters which is approximately 30 feet, square turning area by our city code.

Backing into gate may be a bit easier.

Try on a open area with blocks used as your width and corners of the gate.

Comment: OP has feet - how do the meters compare?

Comment: I edited my answer to convert the units to feet. However the name of the car is Indian. Thank you.

Comment: A name that has been used by several manufacturers...

Comment: Right. The rest of my comment is just padding to make up to minimum.

Comment: Minimum is 15..

Answer (score 0):

If SUV has a turning radius of 5.6m =18.5 ft then the road is not wide enough or you need a curved driveway across property to reach gate 20' from road.